# Example of an extension that is normal but not separable

Tags: galois-theory

My textbook says the extension $\mathbb{F}_p(T)/\mathbb{F}_p(T^p)$ is normal but not separable because the minimal polynomial of $T$ is not separable.

I know that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $X^p-T^p$ but why isn't it separable? and why is this extension normal?

Comment: It isn't separable because its unique root, namely $\;T\;$ , is a multiple one.

Comment: Why is $T$ unique and multiple?

Comment: Because we're in in  modulo $\;p\;$ , so we have that on $\;\Bbb F_p(T)\;,\;\;x^p-T^p=\left(x-T)\right)^p\;$ ...Unique root of multiplicity $\;p\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

(1) The extension is normal because it is the splitting field of the irreducible polynomial $\;x^p-T^p\in\Bbb F_p(T^p)[x]\;$

(2) It isn't a separable polynomial since its unique root $\;T\;$ is multiple.